# How to unit test controller action with json body?

Tags: json, playframework, spec2

Lets say I have a case class with json writer provided

```
val song1 = Song("Song one", "Artist 1", "Song url 1")
```

I then try to invoke a controller action `create` with parser `Action(parse.json)`

```
adminController.create(FakeRequest().withHeaders(CONTENT_TYPE -> "text/json").withJsonBody(Json.toJson(song1))).run
```

I got an error

```
[Invalid Json: No content to map due to end-of-inpu at [Source: [B@1ad542ff; line: 1, column: 1]]
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the `.withJsonBody` is meant for internal use. Just use

```
val json = /* some JsValue */
FakeRequest().withBody(json)
```

and the request will be automatically parsed correctly with the correct headers.